# How to bypass wordpress login screen

Tags: php, wordpress, session, cookies, autologin

Basically i want to auto login the user in wordpress, when he clicks on a link in his email, that bears a parameter of either user id, username or email.

I went researching where the Wordpress stores the session information after login.

In my theme's **header.php**, when i put:

`<?php print_r($_COOKIE); print_r($_SESSION); ?>`

and logged in as **admin**, i got only this one array of **$_COOKIE**, as wordpress does not use sessions internally.

```
Array
(
    [wordpress_test_cookie] => WP Cookie check
    [wordpress_logged_in_80d2ab9fd1f16a2a89ddb8a5553b4463] => admin|1391841132|58e4ae330b4ca7aef9d6a8ffa3c3a1fb
)
```

I also compared the database dumps before and after login, and there is no change.
From this, i came to the conclusion that Wordpress stores the session data in the form of cookies.

Now i would like to bypass the login screen of Wordpress, when the user clicks on the link in his email.

I want to know what data is stored inside the above array of cookies.
So i can create my own data dynamically and push it in the **$_COOKIE** array, to auto login the user.

Can anyone throw some light on this? I am not interested in trying any plugins. I want to do it manually for now.

**EDIT**: I came across [**this question**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53503/can-i-programmatically-login-a-user-without-a-password/128445#128445), that talks about programmatic login of a user, if we just know his username.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, i could setup a script in the root of my site, that handles the automatic login of a user, when he clicks on the link in his email. The link has 2 parameters: his username and md5 string of his email.

For example, if the username is '**sam**' and his email is '**samuel@example.com**', the sample link in his email will be like:

> http://www.example.com/user-login.php?username=sam&rand=ddb4b1cd8f56f9946b76399abb9d3106

Then finally the **user-login.php** script goes like this:

```
<?php
require_once ('wp-config.php');

if(isset($_GET['username']) && $_GET['username'] != '' && 
isset($_GET['rand']) && $_GET['rand'] != '')
{
    $username = trim($_GET['username']);
    $rand = trim($_GET['rand']);

    global $wpdb;
    $user_details = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT id, user_email FROM wp_users 
    WHERE user_login='".$username."'");

    if(! $user_details->id)
    {
        die("Error: Not a valid user");
    }
    else
    {
        $rand_email = md5($user_details->user_email);
        if($rand_email != $rand)
        {
            die("Error: Invalid URL");
        }
        else {
            $user = get_user_by('login', $username );

            if ( !is_wp_error( $user ) )
            {
                wp_clear_auth_cookie();
                wp_set_current_user ( $user->ID );
                wp_set_auth_cookie  ( $user->ID );
                $redirect_to = get_option('siteurl');
                wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to );
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
else {
    die("Error: Missing params");
}
?>
```

This way, when the user clicks on the link in his email, he will be automatically logged in and navigates to the home page.

Thanks to [**Sjoerd Linders**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/128445/18397) for providing me an insight in his answer.

Comment: Hi, I am new to Wordpress, can you please elaborate where to keep this script... I do need to implement same functionality

Comment: @Ashish_B You can keep this script in the root folder of your wordpress installation.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you concatenate a long secret string (aka 'salt') to the email address before hashing it and use a better hash like SHA256 - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

Comment: As a hacker, I totally disagreed with this insecure code: `$user_details = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT id, user_email FROM wp_users WHERE user_login='".$username."'");`. You don't think about SQL injection? You should filter the username first. Suck the worst code ever, when the admin will lose everything from his server by running this code.

Answer (score 2):

Well besides the fact that this would be a huge security risk, you could do it with java script and send a POST to the url: www.site.com/wp-admin/admin.php with the username and password (make sure to name the variables the same as the name tag on the userlogin table in your wordpress).  Then I think you will need to refresh just do a javascript refresh to the dir /wp-admin/ .

Comment: Inside 'wp-admin/admin.php', i did not find any logic for handling user login. Instead of writing my own code there, i chose to create a new php file.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a *really bad idea* (tm). On the one hand you're opening up your website to scriptable attacks (guess the cookie and username, you're in), and on the other hand you're encouraging people to just click on a link to login to something (that sounds ... phish-y, and something which any half decent modern mail client would mark as malware).

That's not good security practice.

Before going further down this path, ask yourself: What could go wrong if a badguy snarfs a copy of an email with an automatic login link?

What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: These days, many sites enable auto-login, when the corresponding user clicks on the link in his email. (ex. mail with any job news update). I want to implement this feature. I can pass a random string along with user's email in the link, to verify the real identity.

Comment: As best I'm aware, that's implemented by setting a cookie in the browser. The user still has to provide suitable credentials to login first, and then the site sets the cookie - generally with a long expiry time.